# "Cannot override final method Exception::__clone()"

Tags: php, exception

I'm getting the following strange error message whenever I attempt to run my script.

There is nothing I could see that would be causing the problem - in fact, the only thing in my script right now that deals with exceptions at all (they are the building blocks of a future addition) are the following lines:

```
class NoMatchingRouteException extends \RuntimeException { }

class HandlerException extends \RuntimeException { }

class HandlerMissingException extends HandlerException { }

class HandlerInaccessibleException extends HandlerException { }
```

These are various exceptions that form a tree of various exceptions I can throw.

**Nowhere** in here am I ever overriding the Exception class's __clone magic method, so I can't see where the problem is occurring.

I understand that, as it stands, my question may be hard to answer - thus, if you have any ideas where I should look for the problem and or what additional code I should look for to post, please post them in the comments and I will try to reply ASAP.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got the full error? it should end with "in [filename] on line [line]"...

Comment: Yes, I have gotten the full error - in fact, I have gotten a full stack trace. Unfortunately, the line in question (line 32, in marathon.php) merely points to a declaration of the Marathon class, which extends nothing.

Comment: can you edit your post with the class in question, please?  There's something *weird* going on here, and we'll need to see the actual code to figure it out.

Comment: @Charles: thanks for your reply; fortunately, I managed to rid myself of the strange error (albeit accidentally) when I changed some architecture. I agree that the error is very weird, and would love to post the class in question - unfortunately, I can't revert back to it. Thanks!

Comment: you should post that as an answer and mark it accepted to get this question off of the "needs an answer" list.  Glad you fixed it, though I'm sad that we won't be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to rid myself of the strange error (albeit accidentally) when I changed some architecture. I agree that the error is very weird, and would love to post the class in question - unfortunately, I can't revert back to it (I know, I know. ;). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've had this error when I mistakenly used

> include

for an overridden exception class twice.

When I changed back to include_once, the error went away.

Comment: Got the exact same error caused by using require twice on a file. Removing it / replacing the require by require_once solved it.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when you define class more than once. So avoid defining classes inside functions and use require_once for .inc files.